# start pyspark cluster with jupyter notebook

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

i'm buildind a pyspark app using jupyter notebook , so far i'm using it in a standalone mode.

Now i have in my disposition 3 Virtual machines with spark on them, and i want to start Pyspark in a cluster.

Here is my code to start it in standalone mode :
[image]

knowing i'm using spark 3.1.2 hadoop 3.2

i've searched for ways to do it and i didn't get it, and there are some articles saying that pyspark doesn't work in clusters, so please if you know how i can change this code and launch my session in a cluster please help.

thank you.

Comment: What happens if you use `local[2]` instead of `local[3]`  to account for zero-based indexing?  Or, reverse the `master` and `appName` sections?

Comment: @MarkMoretto when use  local[2]  spark uses just 2 cores instead of 3  i guess, as for reversing i don't think it's relevant , if i'm wrong please correct me

Comment: You're probably right, lol.  Is there a specific address for the VMs?  Otherwise, there doesn't seem to be a problem with how your code is strucutred. https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder.master.html

Comment: @MarkMoretto when i put the master's adress how will the slave nodes connect to each other ? and form a cluster?

Answer (score 0):

You most have a cluster of some sort.
I use kubernutes and https://github.com/bjornjorgensen/jlpyk8s

This way I have a notebook that interactive run pyspark on.